# Spark UI stage and SQL reporting different task time for single partition

Tags: apache-spark

#### Stages tab

I am trying to analyze a seeming bottleneck in my stages UI:

[image: stages single partition bottleneck]

According to the events timeline, I have a single partition skew taking 3 minutes to calculate. This partition corresponds to task 116665.

Is it actually skew?

[image]

[image]

[image]

The input sizes are all well distributed. This doesn't seem like data skew. It's only the output that is weirdly much larger.

I have no idea why this is, and it's been my focus to try and resolve this, as I don't want a single partition bottlenecking the stage for 3 minutes. I have it in a few other stages spread across my different applications, so I would like to understand this.

#### SQL tab

While investigating this, I opened the SQL tab and checked out the task 116665:

[image]

You can see in the top left that the task is only found 3 times, and I have captured all 3 appearances of the task in the above screenshot.

#### Problem:

The task 116665 is involved in 2 steps: an exchange and a ShuffleHashJoin. Each of these take only 7.3 and 37.4 seconds, respectively, for a combined 44.7 seconds—**not** 3 minutes as stated in the Stages tab.

However, the WholeStageCodeGen descriptor on the far right shows 3.9 minutes for stage 3252 and task 116665. Meanwhile, the stage 3252 only showed 3.7 minutes. If I look for every occurrence of stage 3252 in the SQL tab, it actually adds up to over 5 minutes—well over 3.7 minutes.

[image]

#### Summary

1. The stages tab shows a single partition taking 3 minutes, but the SQL tab shows the same task only needing 44.7 seconds, a factor of 4x difference!
2. The stages tab indicates a duration of 3.7 minutes, the SQL tab 3.9 minutes. If I add up all the times in the SQL tab for the stage 3252, it actually comes out to 5.5 minutes.

It seems the UI isn't consistent, like there's a display error.

My instinct was to assume the WholeStageCodeGen was an aggregate time that summed up all parallel processing; however, the stages tab shows that literally 3 minutes of it comes from a single partition. So clearly it's supposed to come from a single, non-parallelized task, and yet the task time is very different between the Stages and SQL tabs.

#### Question

It seems there are display disparities here that can't be attributed to parallelism. How could this come about? Which do I trust?

##### notes

The code is essentially ~140 lines of a series of left and inner joins written in Spark SQL.

Spark 3.2.0